# How to set color in odd and even position in recyclerview?

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

Position break in recyclerview
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EZADHjrpn8ZwryvQ6qPf1xU1hcG0-Mgf/view?usp=drivesdk)

Answer (score 6):

You can get this by following manner.

Add this code to your **onBindViewHolder()** method of adapter. Like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
  if(position % 2 == 0) 
  {
     //holder.rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
     holder.rootView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
  }
  else 
  {
     //holder.rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
     holder.rootView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
  }
}
```

After that surround your layout xml file that contains card design for example like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/rootView"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="72dp"
android:background="@color/my_white"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/folder_icon"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/folder_icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/folder_name"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="The Mills"
    android:textColor="@color/my_blue"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/folder_content_icon"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:src="@drawable/folder_content_icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/content_number"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="3"
    android:textColor="@color/my_blue"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

After that create variable in your **View Holder** class of adapter like this:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    LinearLayout rootView;//newly added field
    public ViewHolder(View view)
    {
        super(view);
        rootView=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.rootView);
     }
}
```

It will work for you to get the required results.

Comment: You welcome @ShreyDhingani . Can you please accept my answer as it helped you.

Comment: @ShreyDhingani you require to click the tick mark at the left side start of answer below upvote to accept it. Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @ShreyDhingani Anyways what important is that it helped you to resolve your issue. Good luck and happy coding.

Comment: thanks for clever solution! am just wondering, is there anywhere to set the color from the xml?